# How to enable console.log in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, console.log

I use ExtJS and include the framework with `<script src="ext/ext-dev.js"></script>`.

Despite the fact that the ExtJS documentation makes extensive use of console.log, this function is not working, because it is somehow redefined to an empty function.

How can I enable `console.log` in ExtJS ? Is there a configuration option that I need to set on application loading ? Or is there another function used to log to the console ? (I found `Ext.log`, but it does not log to the console neither.)

ExtJS is redefining `console.log`. Outsite of ExtJs, `alert(console.log);` will output `function log() { [native code ] }`, inside of ExtJS, it will output only `function log() {}`, and `console.log('message');` does nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ExtJS does no such thing, as you can see by visiting for example [ExtJS API docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api), which run on ExtJS, opening the console and running `console.log()`. Something else in your code must be causing this.